# How can I write accented letter "ő" in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, hungarian

I'd like to write accented (hungarian) letters in PSTricks. With the solution below I can write "é", "á" and other similar characters but this doesn't work for "ő".

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(0,0)(12,2.8)

% edge
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt, arrowsize=8pt]{->}(1,1)(2,2)
\qdisk(1,1){2pt}
\uput[245](1,1){$u$}
\qdisk(2,2){2pt}
\uput[295](2,2){$v$}

% matrix
\psframe(4,0.2)(8,2.4)

% row u
\psline(4,1.5)(8,1.5)
\psline(4,2)(8,2)
\uput[180](4,1.75){$u$}
\rput(6,1.7){$-1$}

% row v
\psline(4,.5)(8,.5)
\psline(4,1)(8,1)
\uput[180](4,.75){$v$}
\rput(6,.7){$+1$}

% column e
\psline(5.7,.2)(5.7,2.4)
\psline(6.3,.2)(6.3,2.4)
\uput[90](6,2.3){$e$}

% explanations
\uput[0](9,2){$+1: e$ belépő él} % the problem is here
\uput[0](9,1.5){$-1: e$ kilépő él} %the problem is here as well

\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

I tried to write "\"o" instead of "ő" but that didn't work really well (it made "ö" with simple dots instead of long accents)

The following works with pdfLaTeX (for all hungarian letters) but not with PStricks (with XeLaTeX).

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
```

Are there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried `\H{o}`?

Comment: `t1enc` is obsolete. Use `[T1]{fontenc}` instead.

Comment: I just realised you are trying to use XeLaTeX. In that case, you should not load `inputenc` or `t1enc` at all. XeLaTeX expects `utf8` input by default. If you remove those commands, does it work then?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It hardly seemed to count as an answer, but there it is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `t1enc` is obsolete as of `latex2e`. `\usepackage{t1enc}` should be replaced with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in documents compiled with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX. (See [l2tabu](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) for details.)

However, you are using XeLaTeX. XeLaTeX expects UTF8 input by default and does not expect encoding specifications of the kind LaTex and pdfLaTeX use. So neither `fontenc` nor `inputenc` should be used at all in this case.

Removing these packages alone is problematic because loading `babel` with `magyar` requires them.

The solution is to use `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{magyar}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(0,0)(12,2.8)

% edge
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt, arrowsize=8pt]{->}(1,1)(2,2)
\qdisk(1,1){2pt}
\uput[245](1,1){$u$}
\qdisk(2,2){2pt}
\uput[295](2,2){$v$}

% matrix
\psframe(4,0.2)(8,2.4)

% row u
\psline(4,1.5)(8,1.5)
\psline(4,2)(8,2)
\uput[180](4,1.75){$u$}
\rput(6,1.7){$-1$}

% row v
\psline(4,.5)(8,.5)
\psline(4,1)(8,1)
\uput[180](4,.75){$v$}
\rput(6,.7){$+1$}

% column e
\psline(5.7,.2)(5.7,2.4)
\psline(6.3,.2)(6.3,2.4)
\uput[90](6,2.3){$e$}

% explanations
\uput[0](9,2){$+1: e$ belépő él} % the problem is here
\uput[0](9,1.5){$-1: e$ kilépő él} %the problem is here as well

\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Accents with <code>polyglossia</code> and XeLaTeX]

Comment: 1. You misspelled `magyar`. 2. The `magyar` module of `polyglossia` is useless as a replacement of `babel` for multiple reasons; for example, it replaces `Chapter 5` with `fejezet 5` instead of the correct `5. fejezet`. I have no problems with typesetting an 50 page lecture note with `[magyar]{babel}` and XeLaTeX, but not this MWE.

Comment: @marczellm That should be reported as a bug against `polyglossia`. Can you use `babel` here without loading either `inputenc` or `t1enc`? I got errors when I tried this. The latter shouldn't be used even with regular latex. Neither should be used with xelatex.

Comment: I've got it sorted now. It's weird, because (Lua/Xe)TeX expect UTF-8 input, but the accented characters do not appear by default, only when `fontspec` is loaded. It's absolutely independent of whether you load `babel` or not. So the solution for all accented characters is to load `fontspec`.

Comment: @marczellm I don't know all that much about (Lua/Xe)TeX. (I've used it a bit experimentally but mostly use pdfTeX.) By default, you are using Latin Modern but I'm not certain why that would need `fontspec` to get accented characters, I'm afraid. You will want `polyglossia` (or `babel`) to get correct hyphenation patterns, though. Although the `babel` package also enables some language-specific characters, I suspect `polyglossia` does not on the grounds that that side of things is better handled as part of font config with (Lua/Xe)TeX since those use fonts very differently from (pdf)TeX.

Answer (score 0):

ru it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
...
```

[image]